# Error Unable to start activity ComponentInfo?

Tags: android, android-volley

[image: stacktrace]

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Comment: Please be specific with your issue, what steps led to this error & provide a verifiable example. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to attach layout manager to recycler view. Attach any default managers to recycler view with it's method: `setLayoutManager()`